# What exactly was the position of ‘Party Minister’ assigned to Martin Bormann in Hitler’s will?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, germany, hitler, nazism

In Hitler’s last will and testament, he assigns all the different offices and functions prior to that held by him and the members of his cabinet to new office-holders-Dönitz became Reichpresident, Goebbels (briefly) became Chancellor, and so on and so on.

But one that’s perplexed me is the one assigned to Martin Bormann: ‘Party Minister’. Obviously, this ephemeral office as something to with the Nazi party itself, but in all the research I’ve done, I’ve not found a single mention of what the duties and responsibilities of Bormann in the post-Hitler government were supposed to be, and what role he was supposed to have with this office.

Anyone know?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Interesting how "Party Minister" would be read completely differently today, or is it just me? ;-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Context. When I read "Hitler", all thoughts of music and merry dancing are gone from my mind...

Comment: @DevSolar Well, they [had parties alright!](https://youtu.be/WRRG43WBbig?t=19); tastes in music and clothes differ, but I mean, *they* had fun... it was even called "Party Day"! ;-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not funny, IMHO.

Answer (score 18):

First off you need to understand that, for better or worse, the Nazi state did not have clearly defined borders of responsibility. The constant struggle for influence and control between rival organizations was very much inbred into the system.

This included the Chancelleries at the very top of the state: The [Reichskanzlei (Reich Chancellery)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reich_Chancellery), assigned to the [Chancellor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_of_Germany) (head of government). Then there was the [Kanzlei des Führers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler%27s_Chancellery), Hitler's personal chancellery as "Führer". The third was the [Party Chancellery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party_Chancellery), originally the "Staff of the Deputy Führer" when Rudolf Hess still held that position (1933-1941), which was mainly the joint between the government and the Nazi party. Hess was, in that function, literally a "minister without department".

Following Hess' unauthorized flight to Great Britain, Hitler abolished the position of Deputy Führer itself, renamed the "Staff of the Deputy Führer" into Party Chancellery, and appointed the man who had basically been doing all the work already, Martin Bormann, as head of the Party Chancellery (with the rank of minister). Under Bormann, the Party Chancellery grew in importance and influence to rival, and possibly eclipse, the Reich Chancellery.

Note that Hitler's position of "Führer" united three functions -- president, chancellor, and head of the [NSDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party). In his testament, he *separates* these positions again. Quoting that document:

> Reichspräsident: D ö n i t z
>
> Reichskanzler: Dr. G o e b b e l s
>
> Parteiminister: B o r m a n n
>
> [...]

Since there was no "Führer" anymore, the *Reich Chancellery* falls back to the Chancellor, and the *Party Chancellery* remains in Bormann's hands. I would assume that the *Kanzlei des Führers* would be turned into the President's staff.

In the end it was all moot of course, but **"Party Minister" is basically just giving "the head of the Party Chancellery" a proper title.**

Comment: So basically; in a nutshell, it was separating the three positions Hitler held as Fuhrer- Dönitz became Head of state (Reich President), Goebbels became head of government (Reich Chancellor) and Bormann became head of the party, which is what ‘Party minister’ was? Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: @user22453 Well... kind of, but not only. The Party Chancellery, and thus its head, acted (among other things) as liaison between the head of state, and *his* Chancellery, and the various party organizations (SA, SS, HJ, Labor Front, ...). In the end, Bormann was in charge of basically everything not directly related to the war. That's quite a bit more than "just" head of the party.

Comment: I know the NSDAP wasn’t actually wound up after Hitler’s death, so it’s basically ‘head of the Nazi Party’ plus all that?

Comment: @user22453 In practice, the party leader may well have turned out to be the de facto ruler, as was the case in the Soviet Union with the [General Secretary of the Communist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Secretary_of_the_Communist_Party_of_the_Soviet_Union) who was not always the de jure [head of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidium_of_the_Supreme_Soviet) or [head of government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_of_the_Soviet_Union). In one-party-systems control of the party turns out to be important... Especially when the party controls all aspects of public life.

Comment: @xyldke That is quite some speculation though, as Dönitz as President and Goebbels as Chancellor were not exactly paperweights either. However, the point of mootness remains,  given the overall situation.

Comment: @DevSolar Agreed! My comment was intended to show just how important a *party leader* can be in a totalitarian one-party state. Luckily, we don't know how it would have worked out in this case.

Comment: @DevSolar; and of course, in the case of the USSR, which one of those three positions varied between who held them; that is, Lenin was ‘only’ head of government, Chairman of the Council of People’s Commisars-and never formally head of state, Stalin was formally only head of the party, and it was only during wartime that he became head of government. Khrushchev was originally head of the party before he also became head of government, Brezhnev was briefly figurehead HoS before he became head of the party (and thus de facto leader), and later assumed the HoS role towards the end of his rule.

Comment: @xyldke and as for Andropov, Chernenko and Gorbachev, the two former held the positions of figurehead head of state and head of party pretty much concurrently, while Gorbachev briefly appointed Andrei Gromyko as HoS before assuming the position himself, and ultimately scrapping the system and creating (briefly) an executive Presidency for the Soviet Union. None of the last four were ever head of government.

Comment: @xyldke that all kind of reminds me of the situation you have today with the People’s Republic of China (and Cuba, Vietnam and Laos)-the President holds what is effectively absolute power, but he holds that power by virtue of also being (by convention since the early ‘90s) also appointed to the position of head of the party-the actual post of PRC President is actually a figurehead, and has about as much power by virtue of itself as a ceremonial president in a parliamentary republic, or a figurehead monarch in a constitutional monarchy.

Comment: @DevSolar And there was still the Himmler's SS, which was extremely powerful, actually controlling the main means of power (RSHA including Gestapo and SD).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The same testament we're talking about here disposed Himmler as head of the SS, replacing him with Karl Hanke. Who actually ranked 8th on the list I quoted in my answer, after the ministries of exterior (Seyß-Inquart), interior (Giesler), commander-in-chief of the army (Schörner), and commander-in-chief of the air force (von Greim).

Comment: @DevSolar That is true, because he betrayed Hitler. Nevertheless, he was still in the fight for the actual power and Hanke was physically isolated on the eastern front.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава and also tried to make (unsuccessful) inroads with Dönitz and the Flensburg government despite being fired.

Answer (score -5):

The war was over and all those functions only existed in Hitler's head. There was nothing to manage, Germany was almost completely overrun by the Allied forces.

All the title and responsibilities were just hallucinations, allowing Hitler to feel like The Fuehrer for a few hours more. It's a bit like asking: "When this guy with schizophrenia says he is the Emperor of the Galaxy, what are his exact constitutional responsibilities?"

Comment: I think it is very important not to dismiss the Nazis as nutjobs, as it obstructs the view on how the things that happened came to pass, and how to avoid it happening again. While many of their ideas and concepts seem outrageous in hindsight, they were no more or less insane than those who follow in their footsteps today, and actually had their reasons for what they were doing.

Comment: @DevSolar We are talking about Hitler's Last Will and Testament ie the Flemsburg government. By that time, Hitler was definitely a nutjob. Anyone in his place, awaiting certain death at the hands of the soviets, would have become a nutjob.

Comment: Not my point. My point is to not *dismiss* him for that. I mean that while he certainly was *not* in possession of all his faculties, that is not to mean that everything he did was just senseless, because that means to underestimate the threat. Look at Putin, Trump, Kim Jong Un, you name it -- all of them unhinged to a certain degree, but we need to look beyond the shoulder-shrugging "they're mad", because we still have to deal with them.

Comment: @DevSolar At that point in time, at the end of April 1945, he was a nutjob and everything he did or said could be safely dismissed as crazy. He was way past Putin or Kim level, he was literally planning attacks with divisions consisting of a handful of stragglers. It's not about the normal craziness of a dictator, it's about the denial of reality by a man condemned to die.

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty, nonetheless, there must have been some intention in Hitler’s mind, however deranged, to what purpose the ‘Party Minister’ office that Bormann was appointed to. That was clearly the case with the positions of President and Chancellor that were left to Dönitz and Goebbels respectively.

Comment: @user22453 Goebbels was in power for precisely one day, after which he killed himself. Donitz had a much longer tenure, about a week and a half. It's very hard to discern a strategic purpose in the statements of a deranged man. At this point we can only speculate.

Comment: Don't forget Biden, Obama and Clinton in your list of unhinged nutjobs, @DevSolar.

Comment: @FreeMan I won't forget you in my list of "following in the nutjob's footsteps", that's for sure. :-D